# Allowed Website, but still resctricted

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, ipados, screen-time

I've allowed a website. Entered the passcode. But when I refresh it, It's restricted again. How can I fix this.
Apple iPad Air 2.
iPadOS 15.1
Browser: Chrome

Comment: Which iPad OS version are you on?

Comment: iPadOS 15.1 on Apple iPad Air 2